# How to use a random number generator as an independent variable in an existing model?

Tags: differential-equations, random

I am relatively new to Mathematica and I need some help regarding how to create a random number generator to be used as an independent variable for a model my group has been working on. Following is our current base model:

```
 sol[fmaxnW_?NumericQ, fminnW_?NumericQ, fmaxpW_?NumericQ, 
  fmaxnR_?NumericQ, fminnR_?NumericQ, micW_?NumericQ, micR_?NumericQ, 
  kW_?NumericQ, kR_?NumericQ , K_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, 
  mu_?NumericQ, Amax_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, pinit_?NumericQ, 
  tinit_?NumericQ, propR_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{},
  s = NDSolve[
    {A'[t] == -w*A[t],

 nW'[t] == (fmaxnW - ((fmaxnW - fminnW)*(A[t]/micW)^
          kW)/((A[t]/micW)^kW - fminnW/fmaxnW))*
    Which[A[t] < micW, (1 - 1/K (nW[t] + pW[t] + nR[t])), True, 
     1]*nW[t]  - a*1/K (nW[t] + pW[t] + nR[t])*nW[t]  +  b*pW[t] -
    w*nW[t] - 
   mu*(fmaxnW - ((fmaxnW - fminnW)*(A[t]/micW)^kW)/((A[t]/micW)^
          kW - fminnW/fmaxnW))*nW[t],

 pW'[t] == 
  fmaxpW*pW[t]  +  a*1/K (nW[t] + pW[t] + nR[t])*nW[t]  -  
   b*pW[t] - w*pW[t] - mu*fmaxpW*pW[t],

 nR'[t] == (fmaxnR - ((fmaxnR - fminnR)*(A[t]/micR)^
          kR)/((A[t]/micR)^kR - fminnR/fmaxnR))*
    Which[A[t] < micR, (1 - 1/K (nW[t] + pW[t] + nR[t])), True, 
     1]*nR[t] - w*nR[t] + 
   mu*(fmaxnW - ((fmaxnW - fminnW)*(A[t]/micW)^kW)/((A[t]/micW)^
          kW - fminnW/fmaxnW))*nW[t] + mu*fmaxpW*pW[t],

 (* initial conditions *)
 A[0] == 0, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 24] == 0, A[t] -> Amax],
 pW[0] == pinit*(1 - propR), 
 nW[0] == (tinit - pinit)*(1 - propR),  nR[0] == tinit*propR
 },
    {A, nW, pW, nR}, {t, 0, 240}];
  Return[s]]

sol[1, -6, 0.00001, 0.9, -6, 0.01, 0.05, 1, 1, 
 5*10^9, 0.0001, 0.14, mu, 0.02, 0.231, 1, 2*10^5, 0]
```

Where nW represents normal cells, pW represents persister cells, and nR represents resistant cells. The model is currently a deterministic approach to switching rate and mutation of resistance in bacteria populations and we wish to make mutation rate ('mu' in this model) a stocastic variable. Specifically, we want 'mu' to generate a new random number every time step (t) in order to represent random probability in mutation rate (in the range of: 6*10^(-8), 10*10^(-8)). How can we make mu as a random number generator and independent variable for this model? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean, "every time step"? `NDSove` is unlikely to use a fixed time step. Do you mean that you want `mu` to randomly change every once in a while (like, say, every $\Delta t = 0.1$ or something)?

Comment: @march Yes, that's what I was meant to say.

Comment: I don't really understand why you would want to change a parameter randomly in the middle of an integration. If you are looking for the sensitivity of your calculation to the probability, or what the spread is over a range of plausible values for the probability, then you should use a Monte Carlo approach. You would run the calculation many times, say a few thousand, where each time you use one _fixed_ value of the probability that you selected randomly from the plausible distribution. Then you can look at the spread of results from the calculation

Comment: Are you looking to do Ito/Stochastic Calculus? 
Are you looking to do simulation with something like the Euler-Maruyama method? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method

Answer (score 9):

Your code is rather long, so here is a simple example of how to implement a parameter that randomly changes every $\Delta t$.

```
dt = 0.2;
sol = NDSolve[{
     x'[t] == mu[t] x[t]
     , x[0] == 1
     , mu[0] == -1
     , WhenEvent[Mod[t, dt] == 0., mu[t] -> RandomReal[{-1, 1}]]
     }
    , {x, mu}
    , {t, 0, 10}
    , DiscreteVariables -> {mu}
    ];
```

The trick is to promote the quantity `mu` to a `DiscreteVariable` and update its value every `dt` using `WhenEvent` inside `NDSolve`. You would change the quantities inside `RandomReal[{-1, 1}]` to whatever range you need for the random values of `mu`. Running the above code once and plotting yields

```
Plot[x[t] /. First@sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]